# Is combining two random numbers to create a larger random number considered good practice?

Tags: security, random

Suppose I have a function that can generate random numbers of different lengths. So I can generate a session ID which is 32 bit long and a 512 bit long also.

But I want to know what would be the security impact if I combine 16 32 bit randomly generated ids to create a 512 bit one. Will the security be equal to generating the 512 bit id directly form the algorithm or concatenating is same ?

I am using either mt_crypt or openssl random function in PHP.

Comment: I imagine it depends on the algorithm.

Comment: I bet you it'd be more random if you added a random number of random strings. What's the reasoning here? Curiosity?

Comment: It should be perfectly okay, if your source is actually cryptographically secure randomness.

Comment: I actually dont have an algorithm that can generate strings upto length of 2048 or 4096 or something. I can generate only upto 128. So I was wondering if that would be secure. I am using either mt_crypt or openssl random function in PHP.

Comment: @rosscowar  I dont understand your comment. Are you suggesting that I create a bigger random number by mixing the smaller numbers using some algorithm ?

Comment: Well I'm kind of hinting at the great debate of [if anything is truly random](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/is-there-anything-that-is-totally-random) and if any part of your string is "truly random" then you could potentially need no more then a length of 1 or even 0. If the "randomness" needs to be a certain length then that lowers it's random nature. If it doesn't need to be a certain length then why not leave it to chance? If you absolutely want a random 512 character string then build the function to do that in as few iterations as possible.

Comment: @rosscowar "Secure" random numbers in the sense of cryptography do not depend on any philosophical concept of "truly random" or "random nature". Most importantly, many cryptographical applications *require* fixed length, even if you think that philosophically that makes it less random.

Comment: Thanks @us2012 and I'm well aware of that. I've done plenty of research into cryptography and have written a number of programs to do this kind of work. I'm not feigning ignorance to the typical needs, I AM however and already did earlier asking for his application. What are the needs of this application? That would help greatly. If he's going to ask what's more or less secure / random without putting any restraints then I'll stretch it very far :p

Comment: Are you talking in random bytes or random bits?  If you have 128 truly random ascii characters then what you actually have is a key of 1024 bits, which is pretty good entropy for most purposes.

Comment: Well, my function is pseudo random. And if I concatenate two random strings of length 32, then the attacker will have to guess both the strings. so that would take him 2^32 + 2^32 attempts. And to guess the 64 length stirng, his total attempts would be 2^64. Obviously 2^64 is greater than 2* (2^32)...so my guess is that it would be bad to concatenate. Am I correct ?

Comment: Sorry all for being vague...I have to generate session IDs. And I am talking of bits. sorry for confusion

Comment: But then I think that since the attacker has to guess that 64 bit string, his total attempts would be not 2^32 + 2^32  BUT, 2^32 * 2^32 because every time he guesses one pattern from 2^32, he has to generate 2^32 other patters based on the first pattern to obtain the full 64 bits. So, the security is same. Correct ?

Comment: At that point, it once again depends on the strength of the algorithm.    I would expect any strong algorithm to not bleed prior bits into subsequent keys, but buggy implementations have allowed it before.  Keep in mind, if you have 2^n bits, you actually will average 2^(n-1) guesses for breaking it.  If given 2^n guesses you will enumerate the entire key space.

Comment: Oh yes, in average total guesses would be less. But from mathematical standpoint, if I consider the worst case, then my analysis is correct, right ? That the security will be same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the random generater you are using is not broken in any way, it does not matter if you generate the 512 bits of random data in one call, or by combine 16 32 bit randomly generated id's.

The outcome would be 512 bits of random data in both cases, with comparable security.

Comment: Provided the ids had no structure, i.e. they were truly 32 random bits.